# Spyder not working unless in full-screen mode

Tags: python, spyder

I am having a very strange issue with Spyder. When I open it, the display is fine except it seems frozen, I can't click on the console nor the text editor. Once I push F11, everything works again. When I push again F11, everything freezes again, and the display is very weird (see below).

[Spyder issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cmnnc.png)

Has someone ever experienced this kind of issue? It's a bit annoying..

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please close the Help pane and try again. That could fix your problem.

Comment: Same problem here, but....  No, that doesn't do anything, the Help pane wasn't open to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I restarted Spyder in debug mode. I closed Spyder and then I started it again in normal mode and the problem was solved.